# Converting cURL from Swiftype API to Parse.httpRequest

Tags: javascript, curl, parse-platform, swiftype

I can't connect to the Swiftype API by converting their cURL to Parse.httpRequest method. I get either error 400 with info "document" object is missing or info to contact Swiftype.

Here is the cURL that works:

```
curl -XPOST 'https://api.swiftype.com/api/v1/engines/xxx/document_types/xxx/documents.json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
  "auth_token":"xxx",
  "document": {
    "external_id": "1",
    "fields": [
      {"name": "title", "value": "The Great Gatsby", "type": "string"},
      {"name": "author", "value": "F. Scott Fitzgerald", "type": "string"},
      {"name": "genre", "value": "fiction", "type": "enum"}
    ]
  }
}'
```

**Note:** I entered xxx to hide the actual key I am using.

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://xxx:@api.swiftype.com/api/v1/engines/xxx/document_types/xxx/documents.json',
        header: 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        body:{'document': '{"external_id": "1","fields": []}'},
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success(httpResponse.text);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response ' + httpResponse.text);
            response.error(httpResponse.text);
        }
    });
```

**Update 1:** After some trials and errors the following code authenticates but returns that the "document" parameter is missing

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.swiftype.com/api/v1/engines/xxx/document_types/xxx/documents.json',
        headers: 'content-type: application/json',
        params: {auth_token:'xxxx'},
        body: '{"document":{}}',
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success(httpResponse.text);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response ' + httpResponse.text);
            response.error(httpResponse.text);
        }
    });
```

**Update 2**: This validates

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.swiftype.com/api/v1/engines/xxx/document_types/xxx/documents.json',
        headers: 'content-type: application/json',
        body:{auth_token:'xxx',
             document: '{}'},
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success(httpResponse.text);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response ' + httpResponse.text);
            response.error(httpResponse.text);
        }
    });
```

But when I try to supply object into the document parameter it gives me the error "Can't form encode an Object".

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.swiftype.com/api/v1/engines/xxx/document_types/xxx/documents.json',
        headers: 'content-type: application/json',
        body:{auth_token:'xxx',
             document: {'external_id': '1'}},
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success(httpResponse.text);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response ' + httpResponse.text);
            response.error(httpResponse.text);
        }
    });
```

I tried JSON.stringify(document) but that didn't work either by giving me an error from Swiftype "contact support".

Comment: At the very least, you're not sending the right Content-Type, and you're not sending the auth_token in the data.

Comment: @jcaron changed those but didn't solve the problem. I updated the question with other findings.

Comment: Why are you not adding the auth_token to the body as in the original request?

Comment: @jcaron trial and error, but when I do add the auth_token in the body section together with the document parameter I get an error "Can't form encode an Object" b/c the document parameter is an object

Comment: Was that the case with the appropriate content-type (`application/json`)? Also, you may want to try `Content-Type` (which the capitals). It's supposed to be case-insensitive, but just in case... Worst case, you can use `JSON.stringify` to create the JSON from the object before passing it to `httpRequest`.

Comment: Use JSON.stringify on the whole body, not just parts of it. Otherwise you're sending a string inside an object, not an object.

Comment: I tried doing stringify on the entire object and the API does not recognize it as a JSON. It only works when I pass an actual object like { name:value} but fails when the object consists of other objects like { name:{} }

Comment: dont know swift but the $token should be in the headers.    app.parseHeader = (typeof app.userToken === 'string' ? {"X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "eoj", "X-Parse-Application-Id": "qovv", "X-Parse-Session-Token": app.userToken} : null );
  console.log('Parse hdr set');

Comment: Thx @RobertRowntree but that's not Swift, it's JavaScript. Just found an answer will post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work. The problem? Header needs to be a JSON object

Here is a fully functioning example:

```
var bodyData = {
    auth_token:"the_token",
    document: {
        external_id: "1",
        fields: [{name: "title", value: "The Great Gatsby", type: "string"}]
    }
};


    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.swiftype.com/api/v1/engines/xxx/document_types/xxx/documents.json',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: bodyData,
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success();
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response ' + httpResponse.text);
            response.error(httpResponse.text);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Even with no non-ASCII characters anywhere in the data? Do you actually need to stringify the body manually?

Comment: @jcaron you are correct I do not have to. Will update the answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The non-ASCII comment was meant to be related to the need for the UTF-8 charset. And I would think that you don't need the stringify in either case.

Comment: @jcaron You are correct (again :-) I removed the UTF-8 charset and found it to be working, apparently the entire fuss is about the curly brackets around the 'Content-Type' making it a JSON object. Will update the answer.